# NSLog Print when Enter Key is Pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nslog

I am trying to create a very basic app that has a text field and that prints out the value entered into the text field using NSLog when the return key is pressed. The code is below. So far, nothing seems to happen when text is put into the text field and I press enter. Can anyone assist?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfld;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textfld.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textfld {

}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textfld {

    NSLog(@"text is : %@",textfld.text);

}
```

http://pastie.org/9078792

http://pastie.org/9078793

Comment: Implement the delegate method textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: to be informed about every change to the text

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField Will be called every time return key is pressed

Comment: Similar to a response below. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` delegate method of `UITextField` in `ViewController.m`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"text is : %@",textfld.text);
    return YES:
}
```

`textFieldShouldReturn:` asks the delegate if the text field should process the pressing of the return button. Read [more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#jumpTo_9).

Answer (score 1):

set a breakpoint at line 27 `self.textfld.delegate = self;` and see if self.textfld is nil. That will tell you whether you correctly created your property and wired your textfield to that property in Interface Builder. Chances are you didn't...

Comment: When I put a break point, nothing seems to happen. It just continues to run.

Comment: you sure there's no confusion about how to use the debugger? Seems darn near impossible that your viewDidLoad is never executing...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. It's possible I'm not using the debugger correctly

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html for more info. Execution stops, highlights position in code, bottom pane of XCode lets you inspect variable values and step or resume execution.

Comment: Hmm...I put the breakpoint on the line but the program doesn't respond to it (i.e. it's not stopping at the breakpoint)

Comment: You will want to get to the bottom of this, maybe even post a question with a screenshot. Being able to debug your app is a basic survival skill with XCode and iOS!

Comment: Ok - I will follow up..perhaps tomorrow or later today

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",_yourtextfieldname.text);
NSLog(@"%@",self.yourtextfieldname.text);
```